# How can I convert Datarow to int? (C++/CLI)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, c++-cli, type-conversion, datarow

I have a datarow, but how can i convert it to an int or byte ?

```
DataRow^ rw = dt->Rows[1];
printf("ID = %d \n", rw->ItemArray->GetValue(1)->ToString());
```

`ItemArray->GetValue(1)` is tinyint to sql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found it.

```
DataRow^ rw = dt->Rows[1];
Byte ^ temp=(Byte^)rw->ItemArray->GetValue(5);
printf("ID = %d \n",*temp);
```